# Httppost not working

Tags: android

I have created one android program that send data to web .

Here is my code:

```
public void sendToweb() {
    // get the message from the message text box
    String msg = systemId1.getText().toString();
    // make sure the fields are not empty
    if (msg.length() > 0) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://eservices.rondssolar.com/xbusiness.php");

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new           ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "Save    Tracker Data"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("systemId", msg));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "DATA SEND" + response.getStatusLine().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

            } else {
        // display message if text fields are empty
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All field are required",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

My problem is I am not getting any response back.Also the data which i sent is not available in the web .i think my response = httpclient.execute(httppost); code not working

Comment: You do this from the UI thread? And not getting errors? Or how do you use this method? Add the logcat if you have errors.

Comment: i simply call this method from menu

Comment: So no errors, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can post your parameter in Json format like that :

```
Thread tSendToweb = new Thread(new Runnable() 

    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {

            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String message;

            HttpPost p = new HttpPost("http://eservices.rondssolar.com/xbusiness.php");
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try 
            {
                object.put("systemId", systemId);
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            message = object.toString();

            try 
            {
                p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
                p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                hc.execute(p);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
    tAddLocation.start();
```